# change image - javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I try to Change an Image with JavaScript. but it only works when i don't load an Image at first.

When i load an Image a first, it doesn't work, when i don't load an Image at first it works.

Whats the Problem?

JavaScript:

```
   function bild(bild)
    {
        document.getElementById("illubild").src = './admin/cms/bx/'+bild;
    }
```

PHP:

```
....
        echo "<div id = 'illustrationbildgross'>";
            echo "<img src = './images/test.png' width=100% height=100% border=0 id = 'illubild'>";
        echo "</div>";
    ....
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"when I don't load an image at first"*?

Comment: when i don't Show the Image.

Comment: How do you not *"show the image"*? Also, please define what you mean by *"works"* and *"doesn't work"*

Comment: on the page, at first you see an (load, Show) Image. but when you see the Image you can't Change the Image. only when i load an 1 x 1 px Image it works

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here but you probably have duplicate IDs in the document, ie there is more than one element with `id="illubild"`

Comment: there is only one element with the id

Comment: When exactly are you running the script?

Comment: have you tried replacing the image element?

Comment: the script starts when i move over an other Image, when i replace the Image with an transparent Image, it works

Comment: what do you mean by replacing the image?

Comment: when i use another src

Comment: Can it be any vaguer.

Answer (score 0):

Here trying to replace the IMG element...

```
function bild(bild)
{
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("illustrationbildgross");

    var currentElement = document.getElementById("illubild");
    currentElement.parentNode.removeChild(currentElement);

    var newElement = document.createElement("IMG");
    newElement.setAttribute("id", "illubild");
    newElement.setAttribute("src", './admin/cms/bx/'+bild);
    newElement.style.width = '100%';
    newElement.style.height= '100%';

    parentDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}
```